# Write true XML fragments to file from object list

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to take a list collection of objects and write them as individual nodes to a master XML file.  Essentially the problem is I need to strip the header (xml declaration and root) from the results of `XmlSerializer`.  I can't do this with `XmlWriter` because I believe what's happening is Conformance Level rules of the `XmlWriter` determine my xml is then not well formed.  The whole objective here is i'm pulling data from an API in chunks and write those chunks to file, repeat.  Keeping my data footprint small.

```
        public static bool LoadChunksToFile(string FullName, PSCatalog.Page list)
    {
        //PSCatalog.page is a list collection of Item objects inheriting from IList<>.
        //Fullname is full name of the file I want to write to that already includes 
             //a custom xml header.
        try
        {
            bool result = false;
            if (File.Exists(FullName))
            {
                StreamWriter sw = null;
                using (sw = File.AppendText(FullName))
                {
                    XmlWriter xw = null;
                    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                    settings.Indent = true;
                    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                    using (xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PSCatalog.Item), "Item");
                        foreach (var o in list)
                        {
                            serializer.Serialize(xw, o);
                            xw.Flush();
                            sw.Flush();
                        }
                        sw.Close();
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Source);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.TargetSite);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

}

When i run this it goes through the foreach loop and writes 1 fragment to file.  Then on the second loop it throws the following error:

> Additional information: Token StartElement in state EndRootElement
>   would result in an invalid XML document. Make sure that the
>   ConformanceLevel setting is set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or
>   ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to write an XML fragment.

Comment: Can you show your code where you " Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto"?

Comment: I actually didn't post that because it wasn't working.  When I use conformance level set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment i get the `WriteStartDocument cannot be called on writers created with ConformanceLevel.Fragment.` error.  I believe this might be because in an instance of XmlWriter it keeps track of what i've written and writes the header only once - not sure. However I think XmlSerializer still outputs the root node to stream causing a conflict.  That's my theory anyway.  Interesting post on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460208/saving-xml-file-and-conformancelevel

Comment: Is it really impractical to add XmlElements to an XmlDocument, or XElements to an XDocument?

Comment: @EdPlunkett not an impossible solution, but potentially impractical due to inefficacy.  If I understand the classes correctly, XmlDocument loads the file into memory causing us to be very inefficient when marshaling large sets of data.  Plus, I think we would still have to contend XmlSerializer outputting header data for each iteration of my foreach loop.